# Delphi 5 and Windows 7 Issue

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-5

This is a weird one.   I've now installed Delphi 5, updated to service pack 1, on my brand new Windows 7 64-bit machine.  It seems to function well enough, but when I start it up an error message comes up telling me that the system cannot rename Delphi32.$$$ to Delphi32.dro.   I thought "Okay" and went in to rename it manually, only to find that there was no Delphi32.$$$ but there, large as life, was a Delphi32.dro ...

I'm logged on to an administrator-level account, so I figure it isn't a permissions issue.

I'm willing to live with this slight annoyance, but I am worried that it is symptomatic of some deeper problem.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Uninstall Delphi, and install it somewhere else other than in the Program Files directory (such as C:\Delphi). This is indeed a rights issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Do you mean Windows user permissions?

Comment: Yes. Even running as an admin, Win7 puts some limits on where applications can write. Program Files is off-limits except to applications explicitly started using "Run as Administrator", even if you're running under an account with Admin privileges. More recent versions of Delphi properly handle running from the restricted folders, but D5 was outdated long before Win7 was released and therefore does all sorts of things that aren't proper now. Installing in a different root level folder resolves these issues.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks very much.  I'll take your advice.  Cheers!

Comment: When I do this, I install to program files and put a permissive ACL on the install directory.

Comment: @David: Ugh. I prefer not to make ACLs on `Program Files` anywhere more permissive, but that's a personal preference. It's still more work than just installing somewhere else, IMO, and you end up with things in PF (component libs, DCU files, etc.) that don't need to be there.

Comment: @Ken I'm not a big fan either but I also don't much care for programs at the root of my system drive. Same happens with Python installations of which I have 10 for version testing reasons. I don't like them at root level either so program files and acl. Of course, I don't put the ACL on Program Files!!

Comment: Also set your temporary folder to be some short path without spaces. I remember that some tools from Delphi 5 went nuts of default windows 2000 temp path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a user permissions issue.

Even running as an administrative user, Windows 7 puts some limits on where applications can write. `C:\Program Files`, (AKA `%PROGRAMFILES%`) is off-limits except to applications explicitly started using "Run as Administrator", even if you're running under an account with Admin privileges.

More recent versions of Delphi properly handle running from the restricted folders, but D5 was outdated long before Win7 was released and therefore does all sorts of things that aren't proper now. It writes to its own `Bin` and `Lib` folders, for instance, and stores the default `Projects` folder for your own projects there as well.

The easiest solution is to uninstall Delphi 5, and reinstall in a location outside the `%PROGRAMFILES%` directory structure, such as `C:\Delphi5` or `C:\Borland\Delphi5`. Installing in a different root level folder resolves these issues.

Actually, the easiest solution is to upgrade to a more recent Delphi version, but I'll presume that isn't an option. :-)

Comment: And even xe2 feels fine in folder like c:/radstudio/bds16 ;-)

Comment: I'd agree that upgrading Delphi would be the "easy" option, but because I'm doing this for myself and not commercially, there's no way I can justify the large proportion of the national debt that Embarcadero charge for upgrades ... :-)

Comment: I've reinstalled Delphi off the root (C:\delphi5\ ...).  I don't like it, but Ken's advice seemed sound, and so it's proved.  I am having trouble reinstalling some of the third-party components for some reason, but I'll tinker with that for a while before asking for more help.    Much appreciated, all.

Comment: Actually, easiest is to move that file to virtual store

Answer (score 1):

This might also help with Delphi 5:

http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2013/11/11/delphi-6-on-windows-8-1/

Ken White's Answer sums it up nicely.